# Get List of all the Authors

Tags: wp-query, loop, author, list-authors

How could i get List of all the Authors?

author.php file shows the Information about Individual Author.

for example:  http://domain.com/author/bj

that returns the Bj's Profile.

if i enter http://domain.com/author   it returns **404 Not Found**

Author page shows author's avatar, Author's Name and description.

how can i list out all the authors?

Need Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display author's list by using function `wp_list_authors`

for more info : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors

And for author Template Hierarchy see below link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Answer (score 10):

Use function `get_users()`. It returns an array of all authors. With `foreach` it is possible to loop over the array and display its content. There are a lot of attributes going with the user object. Here is an example:

```
$users = get_users();
foreach ($users as $user) 
{
   echo $user->ID;
   echo $user->display_name;
   the_author_image($user->ID);
   echo $user->description;
}
```

Comment: This is more flexible than wp_list_authors

Comment: Note: `the_author_image` is not native wp function

Answer (score 0):

```
$authors = get_users([
    'fields'  => ['ID', 'display_name'],
    'role'    => 'author',
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
]);
```

Additionally, if you want to add avatars:

```
array_walk($authors, function (&$author) {
    $author->avatar_url = get_avatar_url($author->ID);
});
```